# How can I make an applescript controlled iMessage reply differently?

Tags: applescript, reply, imessage

I have been coding my own version of Jarvis in Applescript for a few days now, I have been using iMessages as my input and output as I love the way its portable, yet I now want to get a bit more advanced and start making it feel like it has a use.

Currently I just use simple lines of code to recognise when I send something and then run the appropriate script to send a reply. Such as, If I say "hello", it says "hello sir" back to me.

An example being:

```
using terms from application "Messages"
    on message received theMessage from theBuddy for theChat

        if theMessage is "hello" then
            run script ("/Users/Alex/Desktop/JarvisScripts/hello.scpt" as POSIX file)
        end if

    end message received
end using terms from
```

All good, but I as I said before I want to go further, I need a way it can ask me a question such as "how are you", and then depending on what I say back such as "good" it will run the right scripts to respond to "good".
My current attempts go along the lines of:

```
if theMessage contains "Are you ok" then
    run script ("/Users/Alex/Desktop/JarvisScripts/areyouok.scpt" as POSIX file)

    if theMessage is "I'm fine" then
        run script ("/Users/Alex/Desktop/JarvisScripts/happy.scpt" as POSIX file)
    else
        if theMessage is "No I'm not" then
            run script ("/Users/Alex/Desktop/JarvisScripts/unhappy.scpt" as POSIX file)
        end if
    end if
end if
```

But I know this is far from correct. So, can anybody help me with some code? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing your 'responses' in separate script files. Try using a handler instead.

For example:

```
if theMessage contains "Are you ok" then
    run script ("/Users/Alex/Desktop/JarvisScripts/areyouok.scpt" as POSIX file)

    if theMessage is "I'm fine" then
        happyResponse()
    else
        if theMessage is "No I'm not" then
            unhappyResponse()
        end if
    end if
end if


--HANDLERS--
on unhappyResponse()
    --<<whatever you want to happen (the code inside your .scpt file)>>
end unhappyResponse

on happyResponse()
    --<<put the contents of happy.scpt here>>
end happyResponse
```

As you can see, the 'handlers' are listed at the bottom of your code and whenever one of the functions are called, code is evaluated for them. Now I don't know what is inside of your .scpt files but this should work in most uses.

Comment: I understand completely, and I have tried your code, but I just get an error back saying                                                 "Event: Message Received
File: commands.scpt
Error: Can’t make some data into the expected type." Can you think why?

Comment: Without the full context or seeing the full script I wouldn't be able to tell. If you could, edit your original question to include the full code or provide a link to your code if it is too long.